# Remove first comma starting from end of file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Python3 to edit a JSON file by cutting lines 0 - 51 but because I am cutting lines from the file, the last line has a comma which breaks the JSON. What I'm trying to do is go to the last line and remove the comma.

```
with open(f'test.json', 'r') as f:
    line = f.readlines()
    cut = line[0:51]

    with open(f'test.json', 'w') as file:
        close = "]"
        for item in cut:
            file.write(item)
        line.translate(',')[0:-1] #go to last line and remove ,
        file.write(close)
```

JSON example:

```
[
{"title": "title 1", "description": "description1", "date": "1:15pm Jul 23, 2020", "image": "ImageURL", "url": "link"},
{"title": "title 2", "description": "description 2", "date": "12:30am Jul 23, 2020", "image": "ImageURL", "url": "link"},
]
```

Comment: Why not edit it the normal way?

Comment: `line.translate(',')[0:-1]` doesn't have any effect on `cut` / your output. I'd suggest to load the `json`, edit the `dict` and write the edited dict to json again. This seems less error-prone to me...

Comment: `line[-1].rstrip(',')` try this

Comment: There's many reasons JSON parsers exist. One of those reasons is to avoid wasting time trying to parse structured data like meaningless text. Use. a. parser; sleep well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do something like this (see the inline comments for details):

```py
with open('test.json', 'r') as f:
    line = f.readlines()
    cut = line[0:51]
    # strip both the comma and the new line at the right of the last line 
    # and then assign the value back to the last line
    cut[-1] = cut[-1].rstrip(',\n')

    with open('test.json', 'w') as file:
        # add a new line in front of ] just for the look
        close = "\n]"
        for item in cut:
            file.write(item)
        file.write(close)
```

By the way, you don't need to put that f in front of `'test.json'`, like `f'test.json'`. It is perfectly fine to just use `'test.json'`.